# Do sessionStorage of Ajax Json feed

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, session-storage, sessionstorage

I am trying to achieve a very simple procedure but cannot finish because of my skills and knowledge. 
***What I have got =>*** I retrieve the json feed from the server and it works fine.

***What do I need =>*** as soon the json feed retrieved add it to sessionStorage so when I will comeback to this page again (within the same session) data should be pulled from sessionStorage and not from the server via Ajax. Hope it does make sense.

the code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("weather") === null) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%3D24553463%20and%20u%20%3D%20"c"&format=json&diagnostics=true',
        async: false,
        callback: 'callback',
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function (data, status) {
            if (data !== undefined && data.query.results.channel !== undefined) {
                $('#weather').append('<div class="wcode">' + data.query.results.channel.item.condition.code + '</div><div class="temperature">' + data.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp + '°C</div><div class="details">' + data.query.results.channel.wind.speed + '/с<br/>' + data.query.results.channel.atmosphere.pressure + '<br/>' + data.query.results.channel.atmosphere.humidity + '% humid.</div>');
            }
            var output = $('#weather');
            window.sessionStorage.setItem("weather", JSON.stringify(output));
        }
    });

} else {
    var jsData = window.sessionStorage.getItem("weather", JSON.stringify(output));
}
});
```

the fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/j8QGv/

Please do amendments with fiddle so other users can use the code as example.

Really appreciate your help...

Comment: do you actually want the data object or just the html?

Comment: I guess the whole html block.

Comment: For sessionStorage it is not going to be a huge amount of data to store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres how you can use session storage

```
if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("weather") === null) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%3D24553463%20and%20u%20%3D%20"c"&format=json&diagnostics=true',
        async: false,
        callback: 'callback',
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function (data, status) {
            if (data !== undefined && data.query.results.channel !== undefined) {
                $('#weather').append('<div class="wcode">' + data.query.results.channel.item.condition.code + '</div><div class="temperature">' + data.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp + '°C</div><div class="details">' + data.query.results.channel.wind.speed + ' м/с<br/>' + data.query.results.channel.atmosphere.pressure + ' мм рт. ст.<br/>' + data.query.results.channel.atmosphere.humidity + '% влаж.</div>');
            }
            var output = $('#weather').html(); // get the HTML
            window.sessionStorage.setItem("weather", output); // store it in session
        }
    });

} else {
    // this isn't how you use the getter method
    //var jsData = window.sessionStorage.getItem("weather", JSON.stringify(output));
    var jsData = window.sessionStorage.getItem("weather");
    $('#weather').html(jsData);
}
```

<kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YVwTj/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot Wirey. You are super star!